# Alternative methods for parallax scrolling effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right now I'm setting the background image of a div in css, then using `background-size:cover` and `background-attachment:fixed` to have the image stay put in the background and also fill the window as I scroll.  This works, but there is a lot of repainting going on, which makes it look terrible in chrome.  It looks fine in safari though, which confuses me... Anyway, I want to have several images on a page at different points (after my content divs) that "stay put" while I scroll my content over them without losing a ton of efficiency. What is the best way to do this?

CSS:

```
[class*="bg__"] {
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.bg__first {
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url("../images/IMG_7768.JPG");
}

.bg__second {
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url("../images/GOPR1046.JPG");
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="content-container">
    <div data-speed="10" class="bg__first parallax">
        <div id="welcome">
            <h1 id="welcome-message">Welcome</h1>
            <div id="welcome-buttons">
                <a class="button" href="#we-do" value="we-do">What we do</a>
                <a class="button" href="#we-done" value="we-done">What we've done</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <a name="we-do" class="anchor"></a>
    <div id="we-do" class="content">
        <h2 class="title-heading">What we do</h2>

    </div>

    <div data-speed="10" class="bg__second parallax"></div>

    <a name="we-done" class="anchor"></a>
    <div class="content">
        <h2 class="title-heading">What we've done</h2>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just posted the code

Comment: What do you mean by 'repainting'?

Comment: Every time the user scrolls, the browser needs to redraw the fixed background attachment in order to make it look like it's staying in the same place

Comment: [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sqm7r4dk/) is how it looks? Update it if not.

Comment: yeah that's the gist of it. is it the images that are slowing it down then?

Comment: Maybe, but it doesn't explain the fact that it's not showing correct on chrome.

Comment: It's showing correctly on chrome and safari, but chrome has laggy scroll and Safari doesn't

Comment: There's some plugins that I think can take care of it, like [skrollr](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/) and [NiceScroll](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/). Was it useful?